# Unresolved external symbol in x86 Assembly using MASM32

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, irvine32

Disclaimer: I'm completely new to Assembly so forgive my potential ignorance.

I'm learning x86 Assembly from *Assembly Language for x86 Processors 6th Ed.* by Irvine.

Following the samples in the book, I am using the `Irvine32.inc` file.
My program assembles but when I try to link the `.obj` file, it gives me the following error:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ExitProcess@4`

I'm guessing it should be defined in `Irvine32.inc`. The answers to similar questions suggest I try to include the `Irvine32` library:

`INCLUDELIB Irvine32.lib`

but that doesn't resolve the issue. I am assembling and linking straight from the MASM32 Editor if it matters.

What is causing this issue?

My code:

```
TITLE SUM OF ARRAY

INCLUDELIB  C:\Irvine\Irvine32.lib
INCLUDE     C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

.data
arrayNums   WORD    10,20,30,40,50
count       =       ($ - OFFSET arrayNums) / (TYPE WORD)

.code
main PROC
    mov edi, OFFSET arrayNums   ; move address of arrayNums to edi, will be used to access array
    mov ecx, 0                  ; set ecx bits to 0
    mov ecx, count              ; set ecx bits to count (5)

    mov eax, 0                  ; set eax bits to 0, will hold sum
    top:
        add  ax, [edi]          ; add number at location of address held by edi

        add edi, TYPE WORD      ; add TYPE WORD to edi to go to next element
        loop top                ; loop back to the top

        exit
    main ENDP
    END main
```

Note: This is literally the first program I've written in Assembly so it may have errors. Any suggestions for improvement are also welcomed.

Comment: `ExitProcess` lives in `kernel32.dll` make sure you are linking with that.

Comment: @Jester I couldn't find `kernel32.dll`, but I've included `kernel32.lib` and `kernel32.inc` and I believe that worked. I'm getting different errors now so I can only be sure once I've solved them.

Comment: Somewhere in your program it must have a line like this: `extrn _ExitProcess@4: proc`. On the other hand. I don't see any call to this function, so I guess the `exit` macro at the end of your code is doing that. How is the expansion of that macro?

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix That didn't work. But I'm going to try to write the program without using `Irvine32.inc`.  I'm guessing it's only a library used for demonstration in the book.

Comment: How do you link your obj file?